# How to set bookmark feature using localStorage HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

So I have a very simple code that retrieves the text content of a dynamically updated `<h1>` element and saves that to localStorage as a "bookmark" for later use. I want to have the feature which saves and deletes the bookmark from localStorage upon the click of a button from the user. Here's a very layman code of what I'm trying to get at here.

```js
function myFunc() {
    //Get place name and store it to place var
  var place = document.getElementById("place").innerHTML
  
  //Switch button to display save/delete bookmark
  var button = document.getElementById("button")
  if (button.innerHTML == "Delete") {
    button.innerHTML = "Save"
    
    //code runs when "delete" is pressed
    var bookmarks = localStorage.getItem("bookmarks")
    
    //convert bookmarks into array by using .split
    bookmarks = bookmarks.split(",   ")
    
    //remove last item using bookmarks.pop()
    bookmarks.pop()
    
    // set into localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", bookmarks)
    console.log(bookmarks)
    console.log("deleted")
  } else {
  //code runs when "save" button is clicked
    button.innerHTML = "Delete"
  //check if localStorage is empty
    var bookmarks = localStorage.getItem("bookmarks")
    
    if(bookmarks === null) {
        //if localStorage "bookmarks" has nothing, save place name in it
      localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", place)
    } else {
        //if localStorage "bookmarks" has something, push place name into the array
      var array = []
      array.push(bookmarks)
      array.push(place)
      
      // set updated array into localStorage "bookmarks"
      localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", array)
      console.log(bookmarks)
      console.log("saved")
      
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="place">
  Atlanta, Georgia
</h1>

<button id="button" onclick="myFunc()">
  Save
</button>
```

In my mind, the final outcome should look like this:
once `save` is pressed, the console displays ["Atlanta, Georgia"] and "Atlanta, Georgia" is saved into localStorage.
Once `delete` is clicked, the console removes "Atlanta, Georgia" from the localStorage.

Comment: What isn't working for you?

Comment: `bookmarks = bookmarks.split(",   ")` looks pretty odd. Why do this? Likely serialize and deserialize with JSON.

Comment: @costaparas If you run the code, you can see that when save is clicked, the console doesn't display "Atlanta, Georgia" indicating that localStorage didn't store the value.

Comment: @ggorlen, I did this because bookmarks separates the value with a comma and three spaces, I'm pretty sure that's the syntax that bookmark.push follows.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I was able to press save/delete, and I saw console output ("saved", "deleted") and I saw the values in localStorage

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no need to use `split` and save strings like this directly when working with localStorage.

Instead, use `JSON.stringify` before saving the strings and `JSON.parse` when retrieving data in order to get it back as an object, like this:

```js
function myFunc() {
  //Get place name and store it to place var
  var place = document.getElementById("place").innerHTML;

  //Switch button to display save/delete bookmark
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  if (button.innerHTML == "Delete") {
    button.innerHTML = "Save";

    //code runs when "delete" is pressed
    var bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks"));

    //remove last item using bookmarks.pop()
    bookmarks.pop();

    // set into localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
    console.log(bookmarks);
    console.log("deleted");
  } else {
    //code runs when "save" button is clicked
    button.innerHTML = "Delete";
    //check if localStorage is empty
    var bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks"));

    if (bookmarks === null) {
      //if localStorage "bookmarks" has nothing, save place name in it
      localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", JSON.stringify(place));
    } else {
      //if localStorage "bookmarks" has something, push place name into the array
      var array = [];
      array.push(bookmarks);
      array.push(place);

      // set updated array into localStorage "bookmarks"
      localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", JSON.stringify(array));
      console.log(bookmarks);
      console.log("saved");
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a simple implementation of your code in stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-6wnfcu?file=index.js